# Distributed cache in .net

Tags: caching, distributed, ncache

I need to implement distributed cache in my asp.net mvc 4 application. My application is hosted in AWS in web farm environment. I can see the following options are available.

1. MemCache
2. RedisCache
3. NCache

I am not sure which one i should use. I need to configure session state as well in my cache.

Please Advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NCache. Everything is built in and is open source.

Use

- Session state
- View State

Comparing Redis & Memcached with NCache you could see the following articles

- [Redis Comparison](http://blogs.alachisoft.com/ncache/a-good-redis-alternative-open-source-distributed-cache/)
- [Memcached Comparison](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/comparisons/memcached-vs-ncache.html)